# JavaScript for Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Write odd numbers from 1 to 100.. And I used this piece of code for this:

```
var i=1;
for (i=1; i < 51; i = i + 1){

 document.write(i -1 + i );
  document.write("<br />");
  }
```

Now, can somebody please tell me if this code is right or I can make it better.

Comment: Perhaps its worth a read of this question ->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 9):

```
for (var i=1; i < 100; i += 2){
  document.write(i);
  document.write("<br />");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kX8hn/

Comment: This will write odd numbers up to and inc. 49 not up to 100 as the OP asks.

Comment: Can you please tell me, why can't I use  i < 100  for this code?
Like when I did it, the results were shown 1 to 200 odd numbers.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var i=1; i <= 100; i += 2)
    document.write(i + "<br />");
```

Comment: This will write odd numbers up to and inc. 49 not up to 100 as the OP asks.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong and you can make it better. Start at 1 and count up to 100 in increments of 2:

```
for (var i=1; i < 100; i += 2){
  document.write(i);
  document.write("<br />");
}
```

The usual caveats about `document.write()` apply.